# ggplot2: theme(legend.title) ignores vjust and hjust arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the code below, the arguments `hjust` and `vjust` in the `theme(legend.title)` do not do anything (at least on my machine). The two plots produced from both `ggplot()` calls are the same. I tested if `theme_bw()` was the culprit, but it wasnt. What would be the solution to move the legend title around?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(RColorBrewer)
test <- structure(list(names = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Spec1", "Spec10", "Spec11", "Spec2", 
"Spec3", "Spec4", "Spec5", "Spec6", "Spec7", "Spec8", "Spec9"
), class = "factor"), A = c(0.217031528, 0.370637045, 0.152473461, 
0.08340091, 0.094257483, 0.00619633, 0.043205056, 0.017717884, 
0.004354587, 0.000349229, 0.010376486), B = c(0.312070285, 0.311236549, 
0.139193608, 0.07284637, 0.097903335, 0.003568091, 0.028477238, 
0.021042976, 0.004963161, 0.000374577, 0.00832381), C = c(0.281876963, 
0.326092831, 0.152957419, 0.07237009, 0.10259602, 0.004158686, 
0.026662316, 0.020823785, 0.004313649, 0.00037274, 0.007775501
), D = c(0.275453548, 0.337083347, 0.154469202, 0.070573145, 
0.099172727, 0.005437018, 0.02768352, 0.018713749, 0.003950163, 
0.000362092, 0.00710149), E = c(0.278508956, 0.334527205, 0.154663425, 
0.068355587, 0.101934925, 0.005645608, 0.025961027, 0.019175166, 
0.004090645, 0.000386265, 0.00675119), F = c(0.306981913, 0.328928827, 
0.147765154, 0.058429727, 0.094863912, 0.003795248, 0.024415702, 
0.02349575, 0.003980418, 0.000353114, 0.006990233)), .Names = c("names", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

n1 <- as.vector(test$names)
test.melt <- melt(test, id.vars="names")
names(test.melt) <- c("Species", "Treatment", "Abundance")

colourCount <- length(unique(test$names))
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(colourCount, "Set3"))

ggplot() + 
      geom_bar(data=test.melt, aes(x = Treatment, y = Abundance, fill = Species), stat="identity", colour="black") +
      scale_fill_manual(values= getPalette(colourCount), breaks=n1) +
      xlab("Treatments") +
      ylab("Relative Abundance") +
      ggtitle("Some Title") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
            legend.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=20, hjust=10),
            plot.title = element_text(size=20, vjust = 2, face="bold")) 

ggplot() + 
      geom_bar(data=test.melt, aes(x = Treatment, y = Abundance, fill = Species), stat="identity", colour="black") +
      scale_fill_manual(values= getPalette(colourCount), breaks=n1) +
      xlab("Treatments") +
      ylab("Relative Abundance") +
      ggtitle("Some Title") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
            legend.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=2, hjust=1),
            plot.title = element_text(size=20, vjust = 2, face="bold"))
```

Comment: From [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/element_text.html), `hjust` and `vjust` must be in [0, 1]. Also, please add the call to packages `RColorBrewer` and `reshape` (or `reshape2`), as you use them.

Comment: Thanks.Ill try that. According to https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes the syntax is a single numeric, though.

Comment: @Pascal `vjust` and `hjust` values can be outside the [0,1] range. Furthermore you can use negative values for them as well. When you use for example `axis.text=element_text(size=12, vjust=-1.5)` you can see the effect.

Comment: @Jaap I just read the manual.

Comment: Specifying them within that range doesn't have an effect either. It might be some kind of bug as the [example provided](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes) by @hadley showes it should work.

Comment: I have found examples with guides(fill = guide_legend(title.theme = element_text(size=16, face="bold", angle=0))), but here as well, hjust and vjust have no effect.

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve? If it is to get some space between the legend title and the legend, a workaround you could use is adding a white line to the legend title: `scale_fill_manual("Species\n",values=getPalette(colourCount), breaks=n1)`

Comment: Thats a nice hack.Adding leading spaces also does the horizontal adjustment. That was my initial aim (having the title aligned to the center).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this was fixed recently, but the solution is to use `legend.title.align` in `theme()`

with the example above

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=test.melt, aes(x = Treatment, y = Abundance, fill = Species), 
   stat="identity", colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values= getPalette(colourCount), breaks=n1) +
  xlab("Treatments") +
  ylab("Relative Abundance") +
  ggtitle("Some Title") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold"), 
      legend.title.align=-30, #<<- here
        plot.title = element_text(size=20, vjust = 2, face="bold"))
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7vVX.png)

Comment: "legend.title.align=-30" adjusts horizontally and does not offset vertically in my figure.